# Pathfinding in Java, stepping on each tile once

Tags: java, algorithm, path-finding

I'm currently facing a problem with pathfinding on a map of tiles: I have an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Byte>>`, which determines if the tile at `list.get(y).get(x)` is blocked or not, and the starting position. Now I want to know if there is a path, starting at the origin, which goes over **each** non-blocked tile **once**, and if there is, I want the directions printed out, like 'NWWEW'. I already have got the part of checking if each non-blocked tile is connected to all others (thus, there should be only one area of connected non-blocked tiles) by using *floodfill*, but I still need an idea on how to go on with the 'path-but-each-tile-only-once'-thing.

If anyone has got any ideas or algorithms, I'd be thankful for answers

**Edit:** Alright, I think I've got it, but since the question was closed, I'll have to write the solution here:

(Thanks to @Jack for pointing me in the right direction) First of all, the program checks if the current tile is walkable; it'll then be marked as visited and the direction how it has been accessed is added to the directions-string. After that, I call this function recursively for each direction until the length of the total-directions-string is equal to the total *number of accessible tiles on the whole map* **-1**. If it's not equal, it removes the direction in which itself has been accessed and returns to the upper layer.

Code:

```
public static void findPath(int x, int y, String direction){

    if(pathFound)
        return;

    if(map.get(y).get(x) == 0){

        map.get(y).set(x, (byte) 1);

        directions += direction;

        findPath(x, y-1, "N");
        findPath(x, y+1, "S");
        findPath(x-1, y, "W");
        findPath(x+1, y, "O");

        if(directions.length() == totalFreeTiles-1){
            pathFound = true;
            return;
        }

        if(directions.length() > 0)
            directions = directions.substring(0, directions.length()-1);

        map.get(y).set(x, (byte) 0);

    }
}
```

Comment: I'll star this question out of curiosity. I do not think such algorithm exists (if I understood correctly your question) but if it exists I am curios. Think of a 3x3 matrix as

OXO;
XOX;
OXO;

is your starting position is the center `O` and `O`s are free cells while `X`s are occupied once, supposedly you are using floodfill with 8 direction, you find all free cells are reachable, but you have to traverse the center cell more times.

Comment: @ThanksForAllTheFish but you didn't star it :)

Comment: I guess you look for [Graph Traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal). However this problem is defined to visit each node AT LEAST once. (Not exactly one)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem

Comment: @ata, I pressed `enter` by mistake, was not done with my comment. I did now

Comment: Use a pool approach. Once you take it from pool, its gone and then you have to find a second best tile. Your pool at start will have all tiles and you start taking from it one by one. You will have to keep a tree to traverse back if you encounter a blocked tile.

Comment: Alright, I'll take a deeper look into those approaches; When I find something useful, I'll answer it here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the goal by implementing a backtracking algorithm.

I would use two global variable: the resulting string (let's call it "direction" initialized to empty) and a matrix (let's call it "matrix") of a three-state type. That is:

- Tile not yet visited
- Tile already visited
- Tile blocked by starting parameter

Then implement a routine that given a tile and a direction used to reach it, explore adjacent tiles recursively.
The routine should do this:

- If tile is already visited or blocked, then return
- If tile is visible mark the matrix[current-tile] as visited
- Update "direction" by adding the direction used to reach this tile
- If there are no more free tiles then print "direction" and you've won
- otherwise recursively call the routine on all 8 adjacent tiles
- then remove the last direction from "direction", mark matrix[current-tile] as not yet visited and return

As prototype of routine I suggest using indexes the matrix, so you can easily check for matrix borders

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I am understanding it correctly, so this is what I think you want to do:

you have a Matrix X * Y that has blocked ways. You don't care how, but you want to know if a way from place A to place B exists, that leads you through the matrix touching each tile exactly ones? Sorry if that's obvious but I wanted to repeat it because I first read it as "Iterate through the matrix ones and give me any path".

To me this sounds like a backtracking algorithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking

You start at Position X (say top left) and then make a step. Your accept method then checks:

(a) Is this tile blocked? 
 (b) Have I already been here?

If both of those conditions return false, you step on that tile and mark it as "stepped on". If you're answer to either of those questions is "yes", you try a different tile. If no tile is left, you step to the previous tile. If you arrive at your destination, you have found a path and you can print it. If you backtrack to your origin and have no more steps, there is no possible way.